# id android-приложения

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Вопрос предельно простой, а именно каким способом можно узнать id своего приложения в Android Studio?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под id приложения?

Comment: Я так понимаю это строка в виде: com.что-то.что-то

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю Вам надо Id устройства на котором тестируете свое приложение? Если да то:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textColor="#cc0000"
    android:textSize="32sp" />
```

```
package com.javatechig.getdeviceid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //получаем ID
    String id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    //передаем в TextView
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(id);

  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Если просто посмотреть то зайдите в `build.gradle` модуля `app` и найдите там `applicationId "com.что-то.что-то"`.

Если получить программно, то

```
try {
    final PackageInfo packageInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getActivity().getPackageName(), 0);
    String appId = packageInfo.packageName;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: А чисто теоретически, ID двух или более разных приложений могут совпадать?

Comment: @Вячеслав В PlayMarket нет. На одном устройстве тоже вряд ли, т.к. не совпадет подписи у приложений и установка должна прекратится.

Comment: А если говорить о рекламных сетях, то указав там id своего приложения показ рекламы будет осуществляться только если приложение опубликовано в play market или просто установлено на устройстве, где приложение тестируется?

Comment: @Вячеслав про рекламу ничего не скажу, т.к. не работал с ней. Надо читать документацию по конкретной библиотеке.